# TaskRejectedException throw and thread pool is not full

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I use spring thread pool to manage the threads in my project.
But there is some thing wrong when my code is running.
I get exceptions like:

```
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4cfc01ab[Running, pool size = 200, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 40, completed tasks = 7990]] did not accept task: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@6ba9fcd5
```

It throws `TaskRejectedException` when the pool "active threads" is zero.

I have read the documentation and the source code from Spring but have found nothing.

My TaskExecutor class:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(200);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(200);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(40);
    taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new 
    ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

`active threads` sometime is 0 sometime is 10 , never 200 , weird.

Answer (score 0):

In the exception message it has "queued tasks = 40".  Since in your setup you have setQueueCapacity(40), executing a thread when queued tasks is already at 40 will throw that exception.

If you are submitting tasks very quickly I would try increasing the queue capacity.  Threads do not immediately move from the queue to active, especially when the JVM is busy.

As far as active thread count, it is only an approximation. Java doc of ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveThreadCount:

```java
/**
 * Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively
 * executing tasks.
 *
 * @return the number of threads
 */
public int getActiveCount() {
```